# Syntax error when asking if a variable equals another variable in batch

Tags: variables, if-statement, batch-file, syntax, equals

Here is my code:

```
if %magic%==%weakness% set /a damage=%random%*3/32767+12
if %magic==%resistance% set /a damage=%random%*3/32767+5
echo Your attack does %damage% damage.
```

I keep getting a syntax error when I run this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also I pressed enter between the 12 and the second if but it looks like just a space when I pasted it into this forum so that is not the problem.

Comment: Also between the damage. and pause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use quotes around your variables or use delayed expansion, to avoid problems when one or both variables are empty.

Btw. in the second line you missed one percent

```
if "%magic%"=="%weakness%" set /a damage=%random%*3/32767+12
if "%magic%"=="%resistance%" set /a damage=%random%*3/32767+5
echo Your attack does %damage% damage.
```

Or with delayed expansion

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if !magic!==!weakness! set /a damage=%random%*3/32767+12
if !magic!==!resistance! set /a damage=%random%*3/32767+5
echo Your attack does !damage! damage.
```